# Patch Orchestration Application (POA) does not install updates in gMSA security cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have standalone cluster 6.5.664.9590 on Windows Server 2019 with gMSA security.

Successfully deployed Patch Orchestration Application (POA) v1.4.1.

In GPO set "Notify to download updates".

POA successfully find and download updates, but does not install updates.

The Node Agent NTService does not creates repair tasks for installing updates on the nodes.
Get-ServiceFabricRepairTask empty.

Every ~3 minutes the following line logged in System log:

> The Windows Modules Installer service entered the running state.

and after a few seconds, it shows:

> The Windows Modules Installer service entered the stopped state.

Link on issue: https://github.com/microsoft/Service-Fabric-POA/issues/34

Comment: cross posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b07f9b0a-892d-42c1-b9a0-c6212b51c4a2/patch-orchestration-application-poa-does-not-install-updates-in-gmsa-security-cluster?forum=AzureServiceFabric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below section in your clustermanifest.

```
"ClientIdentities": [
{
"Identity": "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM",
"IsAdmin": true
}
]
```